# How does m.ebuddy.com connect to Facebook chat? XMPP or something else?

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to create a chat bot for Facebook that uses MD5-DIGEST and XMPP, but all the examples online are saying you have to log in using username@chat.facebook.com.

I have been using mobile ebuddy that allows Facebook chat (m.ebuddy.com). Mobile ebuddy requires you to use your username and password. I am trying to figure out how ebuddy does this.

It's not using connect, and I am unsure if it's using XMPP because you can log in with your normal email address.

I would say that it's logging directly into Facebook, but that would be a) against the TOS and b) impossible due to account roadblocks from unfamiliar IP addresses.

Can anyone throw some light on this and how ebuddy may be doing it.